# How to avoid the redirection to index.php when trying to access non www urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a Laravel website in production and here is my problem explained with 4 simple url tests:

- **Access**: https://www.my-website.kr/
- **Result**: https://www.my-website.kr/ (all good)
- **Access**: https://my-website.kr/ (home page again but without www
- **Result**: https://www.my-website.kr/ (all good, redirects my non www
  urls to www)
- **Access**: https://www.my-website.kr/subpage
- **Result**: https://www.my-website.kr/subpage (all good)
- **Access**: https://my-website.kr/subpage
- **Result**: https://www.my-website.kr/index.php (not good, I don't want this index.php)

This last test it the one I cannot fix and it is quite annoying. When I access a subpage without www; it's okay if the only solution is to get a redirection to the home page again but at least without the index.php this is terrible for the SEO.

I know these questions about htaccess have been answered many times but I am loosing hope... Even the technical support of my dedicated server couldn't answer me properly.

I have two htaccess files at the moment; one located directly at the root of my public_html/ with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.kr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.kr/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.kr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.kr/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

And another one under public_html/public with the default Laravel's htaccess content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

You might ask me why have I two htaccess at two different location. And I wonder the same. The thing is I have done many test and I discovered that putting the www / https rules directly at the root folder kind of worked better. But I might be wrong.

Again sorry if this question has been asked a million time but I couldn't find the answer that would work for me.

Thanks in advance for any bit of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file taking care of all the redirects (www or not, https or not) is over-engineered.

It seems like the final domain should always be `www.domain.co.kr` + SSL so there's no need to use `%{HTTP_HOST}` as the final domain is not dynamic, or that `%{HTTPS}s ^on(s)` match to extract `s` or not.

The order is correct tho: always do all the nitty gritty redirects/http(s) *before* the framework rewrites.

Because you do that in the parent folder, it's OK. You could put those rules in the same `.htaccess` file too, but you'd have to put them *before* the Laravel ones.

I would start with simplifying it:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.co.kr/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

You'll notice I also added the `QSA` flag to pass any query string you might have in the original request.

See how you go from there.

Also make sure you always empty your browser cache every time you try something new as redirects *are* cached.

If it's still not working and you can change the log level on your apache config, check this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

You'll be able to debug what happens during redirects/rewrites, step by step, to pin point where the actual issue is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Capsule, it looks like I don't get this pesky index.php anymore which is great because that was a big problem. However it seems like the www redirect doesn't work. I tried your suggestion about the mod_rewrite logging but I am not sure what should I look for. But I will keep looking into it. I'll probably mark your answer as solved since my biggest concern is gone.

Comment: Weird, because you can't really get more simple that the second rule, which is supposed to take care of the non www to www redirect. Happy to hear back from you about any further finding.

Comment: Okay so, in the end I think it is better to put those two rules in the htaccess in the public folder of the framework but as first rules as you mentioned.  Weird because the htaccess at the root of public_html seemed to work at first. Maybe I got lost in the many tests I have done... Anyway all good now, big thanks to you !